# want to set 0000-00-00 00:00:00 value for datetimepicker

Tags: jquery

In a jQuery datetimepicker textbox when I enter `0000-00-00 00:00:00` and press tab to go to the next element it sets the value of the current date. If I keep it blank then it works properly, I mean getting my desired result.

```
$('.date-time').datetimepicker({
  defaultDate: '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
  todayHighlight: 0,
  showSecond: true,
  timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
  stepHour: 1,
  stepMinute: 10,
  stepSecond: 10,
  forceParse: 0
})
```

Comment: Check the `minDate` property. Most likely it defaults to today.

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/CujDK/4/ . it will help to resolve your issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan checkec minDate. It;s not the case

Comment: @DheerajKumar that doesn't fix anything, it shows the same behaviour the OP describes.

Comment: @VeeR can you post a link to the plugin you're using

Comment: @DheerajKumar No I don'w want like that. Actually if I enter 0000-00-00 00:00:00 it should preserve that value but it is updating with current date and 00:00:00 time

Comment: @VeeR please try code which i answered. you have to add callback

Answer (score 0):

You have to add on change event to datetimepicker like below and perform the task in change callback.

```
   $('.date-time').datetimepicker({
      defaultDate: '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
      todayHighlight: 0,
      showSecond: true,
      timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
      stepHour: 1,
      stepMinute: 10,
      stepSecond: 10,
      forceParse: 0
    }).on('dp.change',function(e){
        if($('#dateid').val() === '0000-00-00 00:00:00'){ // id for your input
        $('#dateid').val('0000-00-00 00:00:00');// id for your input
        }
    })
```